# Getting values from ASP charts and placing it into labels

Tags: asp.net, charts

**Charts:**

[image]

I am trying to get the values from the picture above (male and female) and getting it to display onto the labels in code behind. But currently I am unable to get the value.

```
lblMale.Text = ChartGenderViews.Series[0].LegendPostBackValue;
lblFemale.Text = ChartGenderViews.Series[0].LegendPostBackValue;
```

I'm using ASP.NET Charts.

Answer (score 0):

Try with label:

```
lblMale.Text = ChartGenderViews.Series[0].Label
```

**EDIT**

This maybe?

```
lblMale.Text = ChartGenderViews.Series[0].LegendText
```